# Attempting to implement AJAX in asp.net in vb but one of pages does not save to SQL database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jquery

I had a working page that created a salesperson, I used AJAX so stay on the admin page and load the create page and now my create page is not saving to the database. I do not get any errors it simply does not save. I am new to AJAX and I am sure I am missing something but I have been searching for awhile now and need help. Here is my code for the admin page.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="AdminPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="PyriteGoldPresentation.AdminPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/PyriteGoldAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id = "Main">
    <input type="button" id="ViewAllUsers" value="View All Users" />
    <input type="button" id="AddItem" value = "Add Item" />
    <input type="button" id="CreateSalesAccount" value="Create A Sales Account" />
    <input type="button" id="ViewAllOrderHistory" value="View Order History" />
</div>
</asp:Content>

     Public Class AdminPage
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

the code behind the page.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

End Class
```

And here is the AJAX I use.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('#CreateSalesAccount').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/admin/CreateSalesAccount.aspx",
        success: function (result) {
            var main = $('#Main');
            main.fadeTo('fast', .01);
            main.html($('#Main', result).html());
            main.fadeTo('fast', 1);
        }
    });
});
});

    <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="CreateSalesAccount.aspx.vb"  Inherits="PyriteGoldPresentation.CreateSalesAccount"%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/PyriteGoldAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="Main">
    <div style="width: 400px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>
                Create Sales Account
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="column1">
                <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text="First Name"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTextField" runat="server" Width="137px"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column3">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"    ErrorMessage="*Required Field"
                 ControlToValidate="FirstNameTextField"/>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="column1">
                <asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Last Name"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="LastNameTextBox" runat="server" Width="137px"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column3">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required Field" ControlToValidate="LastNameTextBox"/>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="column1">
                <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" Text="E-Mail Address"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" Width="134px"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column3">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required Field" ControlToValidate="EmailTextBox"/>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="column1">
                <asp:Label ID="VerifyEmailLabel" runat="server" Text="Verify E-Mail"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="VerifyEmailTextBox" runat="server" Width="136px"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column3">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required Field" ControlToValidate="VerifyEmailTextBox"/>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="column1">
                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" Text="Password"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="server" Width="138px" 
                TextMode="Password"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column3">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required Field" ControlToValidate="PasswordTextBox"/>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="column1">
                <asp:Label ID="VerifyPasswordLabel" runat="server" Text="Verify Password"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="VerifyPasswordTextBox" runat="server" Width="138px" 
                TextMode="Password"/>
            </span>
            <span class="column3">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required Field" ControlToValidate="VerifyPasswordTextBox"/>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="color:Red;">
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="EmailValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="**E- mail Feilds Must Match" ControlToCompare="EmailTextBox"  ControlToValidate="VerifyEmailTextBox"/><br />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"  runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="**E-mail Addresses must follow the pattern user@domain.com"  ControlToValidate="EmailTextBox" 
            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+[-]*)*@\w+([-.]*\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"/> <br />
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordValidator" runat="server"  ErrorMessage="**Password Fields Must Match" ControlToCompare="PasswordTextBox"  ControlToValidate="VerifyPasswordTextBox"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

and the code behind

```
    Imports PyriteGoldBLL
Imports PyriteGoldModel

Public Class CreateSalesAccount
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles  Me.Load
    If Session("permissionValue") <> 3 Then
        Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
    Dim userLogic As New UserLogic()
    Dim user As New User()
    With user
        .FirstName = FirstNameTextField.Text
        .LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text
        .Email = EmailTextBox.Text
        .Password = PasswordTextBox.Text
        .Activated = True
        .Permission = 2
    End With
    userLogic.CreateUser(user)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What /admin/CreateSalesAccount.aspx returns ?

Comment: it returns multiple fields FirstName,LastName,Email, and Password.

Comment: Did you try to debug in visual studio and see if data is being passed properly ? Without looking at page that saves code its not possible to help.

Comment: The break point I placed in the code behind was not hit at all here is the create page though I placed it under the code I had in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting html content of the Main div . This does not render page as an asp page . Hence it wont be creating click handler for the SubmitButton . It will not call click event for button . You have to add ajax call/form tag for the button to make a post .

Comment: Would I do this on the .js page or the admin.aspx page?

Comment: I found the 
        $.ajax.call(args,unknown) what is it I place inside though? A method call to the submit on the code behind the create sales?

Answer (score 0):

You have  AutoEventWireup="false" and   so the click event is not wired up to the SubmitButton_Click method.

Add a  `OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"` to

```
 <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

Comment: Sorry I have a lot of pages, which one are you referring to?

Comment: I found what it was and put in the onclick, but the page still does not work.

Comment: Does it hit the break point in the SubmitButton_Click method?

Comment: No It completely missed the breakpoint on the page. I am trying to place an AJAX call tag in my AJAX page and adding the code you suggested but have not made it work yet.

Comment: you have a break point on   Dim userLogic As New UserLogic()  ??

Comment: Yes. I tried it on the
'Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click' line as well

Comment: I see, remove this part, it is not needed:  $('#CreateSalesAccount').click(function ()

Comment: Do I replace it with something or simply remove it?

Comment: Try: AutoEventWireup="true"   are you even getting to the page load event?